# Python multiprocessing: restrict number of cores used

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to know how to distribute N independent tasks to exactly M processors on a machine that has L cores, where L>M.  I don't want to use all the processors because I still want to have I/O available. The solutions I've tried seem to get distributed to all processors, bogging down the system.

I assume the multiprocessing module is the way to go.

I do numerical simulations.  My background is in physics, not computer science, so unfortunately, I often don't fully understand discussions involving standard tasking models like server/client, producer/consumer, etc.

Here are some simplified models that I've tried:

Suppose I have a function `run_sim(**kwargs)` (see that further below) that runs a simulation, and a long list of kwargs for the simulations, and I have an 8 core machine.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process

#using pool
p = Pool(4)
p.map(run_sim, kwargs)

# using process
number_of_live_jobs=0
all_jobs=[]
sim_index=0
while sim_index < len(kwargs)+1:
   number_of_live_jobs = len([1 for job in all_jobs if job.is_alive()])
   if number_of_live_jobs <= 4:
      p = Process(target=run_sim, args=[], kwargs=kwargs[sim_index])
      print "starting job", kwargs[sim_index]["data_file_name"]
      print "number of live jobs: ", number_of_live_jobs
      p.start()
      p.join()
      all_jobs.append(p)
      sim_index += 1
```

When I look at the processor usage with "top" and then "1", All processors seem to get used anyway in either case.  It is not out of the question that I am misinterpreting the output of "top", but if the `run_simulation()` is processor intensive, the machine bogs down heavily.

Hypothetical simulation and data:

```
# simulation kwargs
numbers_of_steps = range(0,10000000, 1000000)
sigmas = [x for x in range(11)]
kwargs = []
for number_of_steps in numbers_of_steps:
   for sigma in sigmas:
      kwargs.append(
         dict(
            number_of_steps=number_of_steps,
            sigma=sigma,
            # why do I need to cast to int?
            data_file_name="walk_steps=%i_sigma=%i" % (number_of_steps, sigma),
            )
         )

import random, time
random.seed(time.time())

# simulation of random walk
def run_sim(kwargs):
   number_of_steps = kwargs["number_of_steps"]
   sigma = kwargs["sigma"]
   data_file_name = kwargs["data_file_name"]
   data_file = open(data_file_name+".dat", "w")
   current_position = 0
   print "running simulation", data_file_name
   for n in range(int(number_of_steps)+1):
      data_file.write("step number %i   position=%f\n" % (n, current_position))
      random_step = random.gauss(0,sigma)
      current_position += random_step

   data_file.close()
```

Comment: This is obviously dependent of the operation system, hopefully it is linux :)

Comment: A better solution might be to run your process with `nice`

Answer (score 3):

If you are on linux, use taskset when you launch the program

A child created via fork(2) inherits its parent’s CPU affinity mask.  The affinity mask is  preserved  across an execve(2).

> TASKSET(1)
>   Linux User’s Manual
>   TASKSET(1)
>
> NAME
>          taskset - retrieve or set a process’s CPU affinity
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          taskset [options] mask command [arg]...
>          taskset [options] -p [mask] pid
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          taskset  is  used  to  set or retrieve the CPU affinity of a running
>   process given its PID or to launch a
>   new
>          COMMAND with a given CPU affinity.  CPU affinity is a scheduler
>   property that "bonds" a process  to  a
>   given
>          set  of  CPUs  on the system.  The Linux scheduler will honor the
>   given CPU affinity and the process
>   will not
>          run on any other CPUs.  Note that the Linux scheduler also 
>   supports  natural  CPU  affinity:  the
>   scheduler
>          attempts  to keep processes on the same CPU as long as practical for
>   performance reasons.  Therefore,
>   forcing
>          a specific CPU affinity is useful only in certain applications.
>
> The CPU affinity is represented as a bitmask, with the lowest order
>   bit corresponding to  the  first 
>   logical
>          CPU  and the highest order bit corresponding to the last logical CPU.
>   Not all CPUs may exist on a given sys‐
>          tem but a mask may specify more CPUs than are present.  A retrieved
>   mask will reflect only the bits that
>   cor‐
>          respond  to  CPUs  physically  on  the system.  If an invalid mask is
>   given (i.e., one that corresponds to
>   no
>          valid CPUs on the current system) an error is returned.  The
>   masks are typically given in 
>   hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the following package:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/affinity

It is a package that uses sched_setaffinity and sched _getaffinity.

The drawback is that it is highly Linux-specific.

Answer (score 2):

On my dual-core machine the total number of processes is honoured, i.e. if I do

```
p = Pool(1)
```

Then I only see one CPU in use at any given time. The process is free to migrate to a different *processor*, but then the other processor is idle. I don't see how all your processors can be in use at the same time, so I don't follow how this can be related to your I/O issues. Of course, if your simulation is I/O bound, then you will see sluggish I/O regardless of core usage...

Comment: It looks like top is showing all the CPU used, so I'm guessing that the user interface is getting sluggish, rather than actual I/O bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a dumb observation, pls forgive my inexperience in Python.

But your while loop polling for the finished tasks is not going to sleep and is consuming one core all time, isn't it?

The other thing to notice is that if your tasks are I/O bound, you M should be adjusted to the number of parallel disks(?) you have ... if they are NFS mounted in different machine you could potentially have M>L.

g'luck!

Answer (score 1):

you might try using pypar module. 
I am not sure how to use affinity to set cpu affinity of to a certain core using affinity