# How do you stop numpy from multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I have to run jobs on a regular basis on compute servers that I share with others in the department and when I start 10 jobs, I really would like it to just take 10 cores and not more; I don't care if it takes a bit longer with a single core per run: I just don't want it to encroach on the others' territory, which would require me to renice the jobs and so on. I just want to have 10 solid cores and that's all.

I am using Enthought 7.3-1 on Redhat, which is based on Python 2.7.3 and numpy 1.6.1, but the question is more general.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that numpy doesn't do any multithreading, there is nothing to switch off.

Comment: set cpu affinity for the processes

Comment: @WinstonEwert: incorrect. Try `np.dot` with large matrix on multicore cpu. The libraries that it uses may utilize more than one cpu

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now that I know what to search for, I found this other page that seems to answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575067/python-multiprocessing-restrict-number-of-cores-used

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Set the `MKL_NUM_THREADS` environment variable to 1. As you might have guessed, this environment variable controls the behavior of the Math Kernel Library which is included as part of Enthought's `numpy` build.

I just do this in my startup file, .bash_profile, with `export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1`. You should also be able to do it from inside your script to have it be process specific.

Comment: Thanks. That makes life a lot easier than tasksetting each process.

Comment: I've tried to make a brief summary of things to set in a GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/8a2d1550f5fa4be4fed87d55a522dbf2

Answer (score 58):

Only hopefully this fixes all scenarios and system you may be on.

1. Use `numpy.__config__.show()` to see if you are using OpenBLAS or MKL

From this point on there are a few ways you can do this.

2.1. The terminal route `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` or `export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1`

2.2 (This is my preferred way) In your python script `import os` and add the line `os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'` or `os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'`.

*NOTE* when setting `os.environ[VAR]` the number of threads must be a string! Also, you may need to set this environment variable *before* importing numpy/scipy.

There are probably other options besides openBLAS or MKL but step 1 will help you figure that out.

Comment: Amazing. When trying to parallelize a batch of fftpack+odeint simulations with multiprocessing.Pool, this gave me an up to *600x speedup*! Yet, the speedup was in effect even before I came to the multiprocessing parts of my notebook. Something about thos OpenBLAS threads was apparently blocking proper vectorization.

Comment: Another amazing thing was that the utilization reported by htop was actually lower after the change, so it really seems like some different code path must be used; perhaps something that makes better use of my Xeon E5-1660v4's vector extensions.

Answer (score 21):

In case you want to set the number of threads dynamically, and not globally via an environment variable, you can also do:

```
import mkl
mkl.set_num_threads(2)
```

Comment: what about linux/OpenBLAS?

Answer (score 12):

In more recent versions of numpy I have found it necessary to also set `NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1`.

In my hands, this is sufficient without setting `MKL_NUM_THREADS=1`, but under some circumstances you may need to set both.

Comment: Fwiw, I needed to set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` (cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622299/1666398)

Answer (score -9):

For me, the solution was simple as I stopped using `numpy.dot`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(1e6)
b = np.random.rand(1e6, 10)

# potentially uses multiple threads
dotted = np.dot(a, b)

# single-thread
summed = np.sum(a[:, np.newaxis] * b, axis=0)

assert np.all(dotted == summed)
```