# Inefficient multiprocessing of numpy-based calculations

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize some calculations that use `numpy` with the help of Python's `multiprocessing` module. Consider this simplified example:

```
import time
import numpy

from multiprocessing import Pool

def test_func(i):

    a = numpy.random.normal(size=1000000)
    b = numpy.random.normal(size=1000000)

    for i in range(2000):
        a = a + b
        b = a - b
        a = a - b

    return 1

t1 = time.time()
test_func(0)
single_time = time.time() - t1
print("Single time:", single_time)

n_par = 4
pool = Pool()

t1 = time.time()
results_async = [
    pool.apply_async(test_func, [i])
    for i in range(n_par)]
results = [r.get() for r in results_async]
multicore_time = time.time() - t1

print("Multicore time:", multicore_time)
print("Efficiency:", single_time / multicore_time)
```

When I execute it, the `multicore_time` is roughly equal to `single_time * n_par`, while I would expect it to be close to `single_time`. Indeed, if I replace `numpy` calculations with just `time.sleep(10)`, this is what I get — perfect efficiency. But for some reason it does not work with `numpy`. Can this be solved, or is it some internal limitation of `numpy`?

Some additional info which may be useful:

- I'm using OSX 10.9.5, Python 3.4.2 and the CPU is Core i7 with (as reported by the system info) 4 cores (although the above program only takes 50% of CPU time in total, so the system info may not be taking into account hyperthreading).
- when I run this I see `n_par` processes in `top` working at 100% CPU
- if I replace `numpy` array operations with a loop and per-index operations, the efficiency rises significantly (to about 75% for `n_par = 4`).

Comment: What kind of operations are you doing? On my machine, some `numpy` operations are automatically executed on multiple cores.

Comment: Mostly array operations (no ``linalg`` stuff). In particular, I don't think the operations in the example above are paralleled (at least I do not see it with ``top`` when I run a single instance of ``test_func``).

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105726/multiprocessing-incompatible-with-numpy?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639779/what-determines-whether-different-python-processes-are-assigned-to-the-same-or-d) it looks like `numpy`'s CPU affinity settings are interfering with `multiprocessing`. Let me know if that fixes the problem. If it does, then I'm afraid this should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @senderle: Yes, I've seen these questions. Unfortunately, the answers are either to use ``taskset`` (not available in OSX), or set an ``MKL``-specific environment variable (not applicable if you're not using ``MKL``).

Comment: P.S. Also see additional info #3: just importing ``numpy`` does not break things that much.

Comment: Well, there are also the OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE variables that one of the answers mentions, and I'm fairly sure OS X has blas built in. But it seems that Bi Rico is right. I was able to get almost a full 2x speedup (my cpu has 2 cores) even without using that variable by doing the computation in a block-wise fashion. The final result was almost 4x faster than the single-core `numpy` version because even that version was memory-bound. I've done things like this in the past, and this probably explains why it worked!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the test function you're using is memory bound. That means that the run time you're seeing is limited by how fast the computer can pull the arrays from memory into cache. For example, the line `a = a + b` is actually using 3 arrays, `a`, `b` and a new array that will replace `a`. These three arrays are about 8MB each (1e6 floats * 8 bytes per floats). I believe the different i7s have something like 3MB - 8MB of shared L3 cache so you cannot fit all 3 arrays in cache at once. Your cpu adds the floats faster than the array can be loaded into cache so most of the time is spent waiting on the array to be read from memory. Because the cache is shared between the cores, you don't see any speedup by spreading the work onto multiple cores.

Memory bound operations are an issue for numpy in general and the only way I know to deal with them is to use something like cython or numba.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. If I decrease the array size to 10000 (and bump the iteration number), the efficiency rises to ~0.8. In my actual problem, where arrays have ~1 million elements as in the example, but the calculations are somewhat more complicated, the efficiency is ~0.5.

Comment: "now to deal with them" -> "*know* to deal with them"

Answer (score 4):

One easy thing that should bump efficiency up should be to do in-place array operations, if possible -- so `add(a,b,a)` will *not* create a new array, while `a = a + b` will.  If your for loop over `numpy` arrays could be rewritten as vector operations, that should be more efficient as well. Another possibility would be to use `numpy.ctypeslib` to enable shared memory numpy arrays (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5550156/2379433).

Answer (score 3):

I have been programming numerical methods for mathematics and having the same problem: I wasn't seeing any speed-up for a supposedly cpu bounded problem. It turns out my problem was reaching the CPU cache memory limit.

I have been using Intel PCM (Intel® Performance Counter Monitor) to see how the cpu cache memory was behaving (displaying it inside Linux ksysguard). I also disabled 2 of my processors to have clearer results (2 are active).

Here is what I have found out with this code:

```
def somethinglong(b):
    n=200000
    m=5000
    shared=np.arange(n)
    for i in np.arange(m):
        0.01*shared

pool = mp.Pool(2)
jobs = [() for i in range(8)]
for i in range(5):
    timei = time.time()
    pool.map(somethinglong, jobs , chunksize=1)
    #for job in jobs:
       #somethinglong(job)
print(time.time()-timei)
```

*Example that doesn't reach the cache memory limit:*

- n=10000
- m=100000
- Sequential execution: 15s
- 2 processor pool no cache memory limit: 8s

It can be seen that there is no cache misses (all cache hits), therefore the speed-up is almost perfect: 15/8.
[Memory cache hits 2 pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3eIG.png)

*Example that reaches the cache memory limit:*

- n=200000
- m=5000
- Sequential execution: 14s
- 2 processor pool cache memory limit: 14s

In this case, I increased the size of the vector onto which we operate (and decreased the loop size, to see reasonable execution times). In this case we can see that the memory gets full and the processes always miss the cache memory. Therefore not getting any speedup: 15/15.
[Memory cache misses 2 pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H8Ni.png)

Observation: assigning an operation to a variable (aux = 0.01*shared) also uses the cache memory and can bound the problem by memory (without increasing any vector size).