# Python script on PBS fails with error =>> PBS: job killed: ncpus 37.94 exceeded limit 36 (sum)

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, anaconda, pbs

I get the error mentioned in the title when I run a python script (using Miniconda) on a PBS scheduler. I think that numpy is doing some multithreading/processing but I can't stop it from doing so. I added these lines to my PBS script:

```
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1
export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS=1
```

I also add these lines to my `main.py`, just for good measure:

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
import numpy as np # Import numpy AFTER setting these variables
```

But to no avail --- I still get the same error. I run my script as

```
qsub -q <QUEUE_NAME> -lnodes=1:ppn=36 path/to/script.sh"
```

### Sources:

Two answers that tell you how to stop all/most unwanted multithreading/multiprocessing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665619/3670097, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954326/3670097

Summarizes how to do it from within a script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53224849/3670097

### This also fails

I went to each numpy computationaly intensive function and placed it in a context manager:

```
import threadpoolctl
with threadpoolctl.threadpool_limits(limits=1, user_api="blas"):
    D, P = np.linalg.eig(M, right=True)
```

### Solution

TL;DR - use `joblib.Parallel` instead of `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
Parallel(n_jobs=-1,backend='loky')(delayed(f)(x) for x in iterator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the main issue came from using `multiprocessing.Pool`. When I switched to `joblib.Parallel` I stopped getting these messages. You can also try

```
with parallel_backend("loky", inner_max_num_threads=1):
    res = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(f)(p) for p in  it())
```

But this might be overkill and may fail (see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126511/sklearn-with-joblib-raises-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute) for a minimal working example).

Answer (score 1):

Runtime fix from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57505958/3528321 :

```py
try:
    import mkl
    mkl.set_num_threads(1)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: I admit I did not try this but it seems that the solutions proposed in my question already set the number of threads for the MKL (and BLAS, and other) library. Why do you expect this to behave any differently?

Comment: @YairDaon the existence of a runtime override implies some other part of your code might be overriding the environment-provided default, so forcing it back to 1 (in the right place) might resolve that.