# Python2.7 on Ubuntu 14, running a single script fills out the cores

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm not using any parallelization in my code, but when I run my script my cores are all filled. Using htop I can see that all my cores are at 100%; on each core, most of it is red (kernel threads) and about 10% is green. I can also see in the process list my python command repeated about 20 times.

Is it possible Python does some parallelization on its own?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the script one you wrote yourself in its entirety? Are you calling any packages?

Comment: I'm using numpy for calculations.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053671/python-how-do-you-stop-numpy-from-multithreading). It appears that numpy matrix operations may parallelize by default.

Comment: Thank you! Will numpy also automatically use GPUs if I have them?

Comment: I doubt it, but really I have no idea.

Comment: gnumpy is used for GPU calculations.