# Python multiprocessing.Pool uses more CPU than allowed

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I'm working on a shared sandbox server running on Debian 3.16 , and i don't want to use all the CPU. So I've tried to limit the number of the processes by setting processes to 10. But it doesn't [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xwyB.png), and it still uses all of avalaible CPU.

```
partial_run = functools.partial(function, **kwargs)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10, maxtasksperchild=1)
res = pool.map(partial_run, product_set_list)
pool.close()  
pool.join()
```

I think it's because I use numpy in the function, which performs operations outside the GIL. How can I limit the CPU usage?

Comment: `import mkl; mkl.set_num_threads(1)` might force numpy processes to stick to one thread only.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga Does this have to occur before or after `import numpy` or does it not matter?

Comment: Good question. This answer provides more details and probably has a more reliable method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665619/8477066 If using that method it most likely does not matter.

Comment: My version of numpy don't use MKL, but OpenBLASS. I limit the number of used CPU by setting the environnement variable OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS to 1