# Why import numpy create threads?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, numpy

`mytest.py`:

```py
import time
import numpy
time.sleep(1000)
print(1)
```

Excute it and check threads with:

```bash
ps -eaf -T | grep mytest
```

And 24 lines show up.

But if I remove `import numpy`, only one line remains.

Comment: For me, importing NumPy appears to create 4 threads, and importing numexpr creates another 4. Pandas is importing both of these libraries. (This happens even though numexpr is an optional dependency of Pandas.)

Comment: @NickODell, Thanks, I tried that, import numpy create 16 and import numexpr create another 8. I have changed title to numpy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053671/how-do-you-stop-numpy-from-multithreading.  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are created by math libraries used by numpy, eg. MKL, BLAS, openMP.

See:

https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/global_state.html

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11826