# Force thread execution on a specific CPU core

Tags: python, multithreading

I have two threads in python and I want to force the execution of Thread1 on CPU core 0 and Thread2 on CPU core 1. Is that possible? If so, how? Thanks

```
import threading
import time

#I would like to execute this thread on CPU core 0
class Thread1(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.running = 1;  
        super(Thread1, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
           print "Thread1"

#I would like to execute this thread on CPU core 1    
class Thread2(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.running = 1;  
        super(Thread2, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
           print "Thread2"


if __name__ == "__main__":
  thread1 = Thread1()
  thread1.start()

  thread2 = Thread2()
  thread2.start()

  start_time = time.time()

  while (time.time() - start_time) <= 5:
    print "main"

  thread1.running = 0;
  thread2.running = 0;
  thread1.join()
  thread2.join()
```

As it is now,  it is not possible to determine on which core the process is running.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/affinity/0.1.0, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575067/python-multiprocessing-restrict-number-of-cores-used

Comment: Take a look at `sched_setaffinity()`, but note that it works with processes, not with threads.

Comment: First of all: I don't see advantage of doing that manually (instead od allowing OS to decide). Secondly: due to GIL it doesn't even matter unless you are using some other Python interpreter than CPython.

Comment: I need to do this manually since the aim of the application is to generate a fixed amount of CPU load on a specific core (it's a stress test)

Comment: Take a look at [`taskset`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html) too, so that you don't have to write the code yourself